# PHP-скрипт возвращает состояние rejected в fail()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Отправляю ajax-запрос к php-файлу:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/engine/search.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        data:data
    },
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(){
        console.log('Request sent successfully. Pending...')
    }
}).fail(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}).done(function(){
    console.log('OK'); // "OK" не выводится
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
require('functions.php');

if(isAjax()) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/', $data['from']) && !preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/', $data['to'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad IATA codes provided');
        }
        if(!validateDate($data['there']) && !validateDate($data['thence'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad date format provided');
        }
        if(!preg_match('/^[1-9]*$/', $data['adults']) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $data['teens']) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $data['kids'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad passengers data provided');
        }
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['search_data'] = json_encode($data);
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('Access denied');
}
?>
```

В нём успешно происходит обработка полученых данных, но почему-то ajax-запрос заходит в fail(), хотя код - 200(OK). В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А попробуйте убрать `done()` и `fail()` в js и перенести тот код в колбеки `success`, `error` и `complete`. Там дело в том, что `success` - это аналог того же `done()`, и возможно если код фреймворка видит, что у него переданы обработчики в массиве настроек, он пойдет по пути их обработки там, проигнорировав таким образом обработчики, которые вы навесили после через точку.

Comment: @Станислав нет, success и error отвечают за состояние соединения, а вот fail() и done() за ошибку или успех в результате окончания работы скрипта. Но проблему я всё-таки вычислил - у меня был указан dataType, который ждал от сервера ответ в виде json-массива, но не получал его. Всё от чёртовой невнимательности :)

Comment: Тогда пишите сами себе ответ и отмечайте его верным, что я могу сказать ) За информацию спасибо, не знал - никогда ранее не использовал `done()` и прочее.

Comment: Проверил ваши слова про fail и done - честно говоря, не понял, все-таки, что вы имели ввиду. Можно как-то подробнее? Потому что у меня fail и error срабатывают совершенно одинаково, да и собственно у нас же контекст - соединение - так что и ошибки и успех - это ошибки и успехи соединения.

Comment: Вот что нашел в документации:
===
Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead. ===

То есть это одно и то же, просто на данный момент существует два варианта получения этой информации.

Answer (score 1):

В теле ajax-запроса был указан `dataType: 'json'`, из-за которого ajax ждал ответа от сервера в виде json-массива, но так его и не получал.

Comment: верняк, echo "[]"; должно биде помочь